# use one macro in different excel files

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a macro, which I would like to use in different excel files, which have almost the same table structure but different data.

So is it possible anyhow just to "include" my macro-script to any excel file?!

I read already [this tip](https://web.archive.org/web/20130926070845/http://office.microsoft.com:80/en-us/project-help/copy-a-macro-HP045304443.aspx) but it sounds for me like a bad joke.

Thank you

Comment: That "bad joke" is a broken link.

Answer (score 8):

You need to save the document as an Excel Add-in (.xla) and distribute that. Users can then go `Tools>Add-ins` to install the add in. They will need to browse to the file you sent them and verify the add-in is checked on the add-in list. Note that add-ins do not show up in <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> or in `Tools>Macro`. You need to make a menu for that in your add-in code. see this post http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/creating_custom_menus/

> If you want your code to be available in all your workbooks, then use your
>   `PERSONAL.XLS` or in **Excel 2007-2010** your `PERSONAL.XLSB` file. These are normally held in the `XLSTART` folder under your documents and settings.

This is a hidden workbook that opens when you start Excel.
The code you copy in this workbook is available in all workbooks you have opened in Excel.

The easiest way to make one is to record a dummy macro, then select Personal Macro Workbook under the Store The Macro in drop-down list.

Open up macro editor (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>) and then save the `PERSONAL.XLS` file. write up a macro, e.g

```
Public Sub Testing()
    MsgBox "Hey im from Personal.xls"
End Sub
```

> Remember to hide the workbook named `personal.xls` (`Window>>Hide`). Now on any workbook, this macro is available.

Comment: Omg, Micro$oft. The problem is, I must send my macro to somebody else. Then the solution you suggested should be done on every computer, shouldn't it?

Comment: Looks like you still looking for an answer on this. I have updated my answer... have you tried it yet?

Comment: +1 Abdul as your answer got me on the right track with the Add-in.  However to finish the job (in Excel 2010) I simply had to: "Customize Ribbon" --> choose commands from: "Macros" --> create a custom group for my command and then add my sub to that group.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options; you can

1) include your macro in your personal.xlsb, which will be hidden, yet available for your use or

2) include your macro in an add-in file which will startup with excel every time. Add-in files give you the added benefit of easy distribution if someone else would like to use your macro(s).

For the tool I'm building, I chose to use an add-in file and it's worked out great.

Put your code in a module in the addin, make sure the macro is not private, and you can even make a button for easy use on your quick-access-toolbar.

Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest, best way to do this is to create a "commander" XLSM which contains the macro but none of the data.  All it does is open the specified Excel files and run the macro on them.  You can either type/paste in the name of a specific file(s), you can loop through an entire directory, etc.  It is very easy to run a macro on a different workbook than the one which actually contains the macro.  Something like this below... piece of cake.

```
Sub MultipleFileMacro()

Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim f As Scripting.File

   Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
   For Each f In fso.GetFolder("c:\samplefolder").Files
      Set wb = Excel.Workbooks.Open(f)

      MyMacro wb

      wb.Close
   Next f

End Sub
------------
Sub MyMacro(wb As Excel.Workbook)

   'do something here

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If the personnal.xls solution does not suit your needs, you can just save the macro(s) to  an Excel workbook, and ask the users to have it loaded (open) while working in the "other" document.
You might need to correct your macro in that case. eg: replace `Thisworkbook` by `Activeworkbook`.

Comment: Sounds much better. I will try.

Comment: iDevelop - I'm pretty sure that having a second file open will not 'include' any macros in that file in the first file.

Comment: @LeasMaps: It works, of course. I have often used that. Assigning a key combination to a macro allows it to be quickly started, even if not in the active workbook. Another way is to have the macro add a menu or menu item, and eventually hide itself. That's how addd-ins are done.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Macro in more than one workbook, either convert it to AddIn or save in Personal. Xlsb file,, and if the Database structure is similar in other Workbooks, your Macro will be useful, but always remember each code has a specific task, ☺