# Error handling VBA (if Err raise skip this block)

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

I am a beginner python programmer but lately I am coding a bit with VBA in access and excel.

I am working in a code that exports some data from two different query's (from access to an excel workbook). Then from excel I keep doing more processes with the data in order to do some sales analysis.

The problem is that sometimes, one of the query's (or both) can be empty which raises an

> error '3021'

What I would like to do is that if an

> error '3021'

happens in a specific block, jump to a specific line and keep with the execution.

In python I would put that code block - that I know can raise the

> error '3021'

inside a "try" to avoid the execution

```
#code here
Try:
    #code that may raise error
Except Exception as '3021':
    pass
#code here....
```

In VBA I was able to handle the

> error '3021'

but not as I would like. Once I have "managed" the

> error '3021'

If another error raises in the rest of the code, the last error handler is always active (hiding other error raises that I would like to raise for debugging. An extract of the code is this:

```
On Error GoTo Err1Handler
'here starts the code that may raise the error '3021'
consulta16.MoveFirst
Datos16.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset consulta16

With APIExcel.ActiveSheet.Cells
.Select
.EntireColumn.AutoFit
.Range("A1").Select
End With
'From here I know there wont be an error '3021'
NoData16:
columnas = consulta17.Fields.Count
For i = 0 To columnas - 1
    Datos17.Cells(1, i + 1) = consulta17.Fields(i).Name
Next i
'Now comes the second query that may raise same
```

> error '3021'

so I make another error exception

```
 On Error GoTo Err2Handler
 consulta17.MoveFirst
```

---

```
Datos17.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset consulta17
    With APIExcel.ActiveSheet.Cells
    .Select
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .Range("A1").Select
End With
'#more code.......
Err1Handler:
If Err.Number = 3021 Then
    'MsgBox ("Sin datos del 16")
    Resume NoData16
End If
Err2Handler:
If Err.Number = 3021 Then
        'MsgBox ("Sin datos del 17")
        Resume NoData17
End If
```

I read [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm)
This documentation about error handling in Vba but I don't know how to handle specific errors without affecting the whole script. I guess I am trying to face vba error handling as coding in python...I would appreciate if some one can help me to understand how to isolate blocks of code inside error handlers without affecting the whole script (Try/Catch/Finally way?)

Comment: If this question has nothing to do with python, you should remove the python code and tag and focus on the issue you're having with vba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have done it like this:

Option Explicit

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim a As Long
    Dim b As Long

    On Error GoTo TestMe_Error

    a = 1: b = 0
    Debug.Print a / b   'Error 11
    Debug.Print "Some more stuff..."
    Debug.Print a / b   'Error 11
    Debug.Print "Some other stuff..."        
    a = 0
    Debug.Print a / b   'Error 6

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

TestMe_Error:
    If Err.Number = 11 Then
        Resume Next
    Else
        MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
    End If
End Sub
```

Thus, if you look for error 11 it would ignore it and continue, and every other error would be caught (e.g. error 6 is caught).

---

This is how to find the line, causing the error:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    On Error GoTo TestMe_Error

    Debug.Print 3 / 4
    Debug.Print 4 / 0
    Debug.Print 6 / 1

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

TestMe_Error:
    Stop
    Resume
End Sub
```

After the code stops on the `Stop` line, if you press twice <kbd>F8</kbd> you would go to the error line.

Comment: So a way to handle different errors in VBA is by using a single On Error, with an if statement inside to check the error and take some actions?

Comment: Is there any way to know in which line of code happened the error raised in the Else statement?

Comment: @DLA - if you write only `Stop : Resume` on the Error Handler, then it will stop on the error and will resume on the exact line where the error happened. Thus, you would know.

Comment: @DLA You can add line numbers and use `erl` to return the line number in an error handler. The last time I used line numbers was Sinclair Basic back in the eighties and modern languages don't use line numbers.  Most of my error handlers have `Resume Next` once the error is handled - I put a break point in the error handler, comment out `Next` and as Vityata said - it takes you back to the line that caused the error.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41001047/how-to-auto-populate-line-number-in-vba-editor/41002482#41002482

Comment: @Vityata I almost get it. Now I can identify any other error apart from the 3021 with stop : Resume But how do you do like in my code, where I need to deal two times with the same error, but the way to handle it is different in each case (skipping different blocks of codes) . Do I need to use two different error handlers?

Comment: @DLA - you need 1 errror handler, just make sure that you use select case or if to catch the correct error number and to act correspondingly ☺ Cheers 

Comment: @Vityata but how can I check in a select case when the error comes from, for example, "consulta16.MoveFirst" rather than from "consulta17.MoveFirst" if the error number is the same?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use one main error handler and catch the different codes and actions in their and use an Err.Clear to reset the error number after appropriately handling. And then an instruction on where to return to.

```
'Other code
Exit Sub

Err1Handler:

If Err.Number = 3021 Then

    'MsgBox ("Sin datos del 16")
    Err.Clear
    Resume NoData16

ElseIf Err.Number = X Then
    MsgBox "The workbook named """ & Bk & """ does not exist."
    Err.Clear
    'Resume Next  ''Example. Instruction on what to do next; where to go
End If

End Sub
```

Or use same idea but with

```
Select Case Err.Number
            Case 0
```

Comment: This code should be outside the main body of the procedure/function.  i.e. `Exit Function/Sub` followed by error handling followed by `End Function/Sub`.  E.g. - using the code in @Vityata answer - comment out the `Exit Sub`, add a `Resume Next` above the `End Sub` and the last error (Error 6) will appear twice and throw a `Resume without error` error.

Comment: Yep, those changes are fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd handle this a bit differently. My query knowledge is fairly weak, but I believe the same principles apply:

```
If (Test for a record) then
'Code here
Else
'Error Handling here
End if
```

This gets the same result, without dealing with onerror - since if you have quite a bit more code, and you forget to turn it off/change it, you could loop back into it without meaning to. I've dealt with enough spaghetti code to want to avoid onerror whenever I could use a boolean instead.

All of this assumes, of course, that you can test for the existence of the records before running the query.