# How to tell if a statement in vba can have a line number

Tags: vba

In ancient times all basic statements were allowed to have or even required to have line numbers. I was writing some code today to create line numbers on all the statements. The purpose is to use the erl function in the error handler to help debug errors. Here is a sample:

```
       Public Sub AddErrorEventHandlerToForm()
1040        Const sProcedure As String = "AddErrorEventHandlerToForm"
1060        Dim obj As AccessObject, dbs As Object
1080        Dim i As Integer
1100        Dim modOpenModules As Modules
```

This is the result of modifying some ms-access code. The simple minded code numbered all the statements. I had to remove numbers from all the declaration section statements because the compiler flagged them as errors when numbered.
It also flagged the first statement of the procedure when numbered. The 1040 statement is not flagged, does not generate and error but also does not add the constant sProcedure to the program's symbol table. So an error is generated later in the code when sProcedure is used.

I failed to find documentation about this topic when searching Microsoft Developers Network for Office vba. The best I found about line numbers was in the glossary.

It seems that a lot of trial and error is required. I'm hoping that someone has done the work and is willing to share.

Comment: Further examination shows that something else is in play. I replaced the changed code with a copy from the original. It compiles ok. I added statement numbers to the relevant lines and it still compiled ok. I will continue to investigate.

Comment: [Relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41002482/1188513)

Comment: `Erl` is broken and undocumented. Line numbering is only "needed" when you have huge procedures that do way too many things and have way too many reasons to fail. You said it yourself, "in ancient times" it was a thing. We're in 2019, don't write code like it's 1985. If VBA is your bread & butter and you really need line numbers for logging purposes, you need [vbWatchDog](https://www.everythingaccess.com/vbwatchdog.asp) - then you'll get *actual* file line numbers (rather than arbitrarily numbered labels), programmatic access to the call stack, and try/catch error handling.

Answer (score 1):

Declarations aren't executable statements (you can't break on them), so it makes no sense to number them.

That's `Public Whatever`, `Private Whatever`, `Friend Whatever`, `Dim Whatever`, `Const Whatever` statements, including `Sub`, `Function`, and `Property` declarations, plus anything that isn't in a procedure scope.

No declaration statement that compiles will ever throw a run-time error. Note that `End Sub/Function/Property` is technically an executable statement, too - but numbering them makes no sense whatsoever.

Note however, that [**you don't want line numbers**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41002482/1188513).

Here's *one* of several ways line numbers can be nasty:

```
Public Sub TestMe()
10 DoSomething: DoSomething
End Sub

Private Sub DoSomething()
10 Debug.Print "did something"
End Sub
```

Did you expect `TestMe` to ouptut `did something` twice? Woopsie, the first procedure call is a *line label!* ...yeah, you can have line numbers *and* line labels together on the same line of code.

That said I can't reproduce the problem with the `Const` declaration causing an error, works fine here:

[image: intellisense showing the const value]