# How to Automatically stop a Sub running after 10 seconds

Tags: vba

Why does this code not stop after 10 Seconds, I am now doing as suggested this does not stop after 10 secs

```
Sub test()
  Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:08"), "TerminateExecution"
  ChangeDoubleToDate
End Sub

Sub TerminateExecution()
  End
End Sub

Sub ChangeDoubleToDate()
  Dim ii As Long
  Sheets.Add
  ActiveSheet.Name = "Example"
  Range("A:E").ColumnWidth = 15
  Range("A:E").ClearContents
  Range("A1").Select
  For ii = 20190101 To 20191234
  ActiveCell.Value = ii
  ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(RC[-1],1,4)" 
  ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(RC[-2],5,2)"
      ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
      ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(RC[-3],7,2)"
      ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
      ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=DATE(RC[-3],RC[-2],RC[-1])"
      ActiveCell.Offset(1, -4).Range("A1").Select
      DoEvents
      Next
      Application.DisplayAlerts = False
      Sheets("Example").Delete
      Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This is unrelated to your problem, but if I can suggest avoiding using line numbers - see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41002482/9245853).

Comment: First of all, add `Option Explicit` and remove any `On Error ...` statements at least while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Sub Test()

    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "TerminateExecution"
    MainContent

End Sub

Sub TerminateExecution()

    End

End Sub

' Add the rest procedures you need unchanged below
' ...
```

Comment: Cant make changes in MainContent() . I have been struggling wit this problem

Comment: I changed that procedures just to make them more robust, since they even won't work with `Option Explicit` if used as is. You may left them unchanged.

Comment: Cant make changes in MainContent() . I have been struggling with this problem for a long time. If vba allowed multitasking this would be no problem . Perhaps there is some way to pass this to the operating system from vba

Comment: @EmanRosent I changed code as you requested, is it works for you?

Comment: I would not like to use "DoEvents".Is ther no other way to stop the sub running after 10 seconds.

Comment: @EmanRosent That is the answer to your question, and actually it's working solution. Please specify the exact requirements by editing the question.

Comment: @EmanRosent I tested on Win7 Office 2010 x64. What is the configuration you run the code on? And did you use `MainContent` and `DelaySeconds` exactly the same as in the question?