# Differences Mac vs Windows with Lines/Paragraphs when manipulating TextRange

Tags: vba, macos, powerpoint

UPDATE

> I found out that the vbCrLf is a vbLf on mac -- and https://stackoverflow.com/users/1188513/mathieu-guindon came to the same conclusion parallel. Now I also found out that in Mac the TextRange is interpreted as LINES instead of PARAGRAPHS.

In order to create the agenda and then delete the first two Paragraphs I needed this code:

```
                    With ActivePresentation.SectionProperties
                    MsgBox "We gather now the Section headers"
                        For iSectIndex = 1 To .Count
                        If ActivePresentation.SectionProperties.Name(iSectIndex) <> "" Then
                            #If Mac Then

                            sSectionCollector = sSectionCollector & vbLf & ActivePresentation.SectionProperties.Name(iSectIndex)
                            #Else
                            sSectionCollector = sSectionCollector & vbCrLf & ActivePresentation.SectionProperties.Name(iSectIndex)
                            #End If
                        End If
                        Next iSectIndex
                    End With

                    sAgendaTextblock.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = sSectionCollector

                    #If Mac Then
                    MsgBox "starting to delete"
                    MsgBox "line 1: " & sAgendaTextblock.TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs(1).Lines(1).Text
                    sAgendaTextblock.TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs(1).Lines(1, 2).Delete

                    #Else
                    MsgBox "starting to delete"
                    MsgBox "paragraph 1: " & sAgendaTextblock.TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs(1).Text
                    sAgendaTextblock.TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs(1, 2).Delete
                    #End If
```

OLD CODE /not relevant anymore:

Sorry, this is surely not beautiful - I am a VBA beginner. This code works perfect on windows, but throws a 6/Overflow on Mac. I know I can reprogram with a `#IF Mac` - but first I need to understand WHY it would throw that error -- it seems to be the line 280 maybe `SectionProperties.Name` when I try to read it into the sSectionCollector string

**UPDATE**

> THE CODE IS RUNNING NOW AS AN ADDIN WITHOUT ERRORS BUT IT PRODUCES DIFFERENT RESULT
>   **Windows**
>   [Under Windows ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7H6U.png)
>   [Under Mac it somehow doubles the lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRCfG.png) 
>   Unfortunately I can not see/stepinto/debug the code in a Addin in VBAEditor :-(

---

```
    Sub CreateAgendaWithSegments()
          'TODO DOCU
          'TODO Implement Button
          Dim oSl As Slide
          Dim oPl As Presentation
          Dim sAgendaCnt As Long
          Dim sAgendaTextblock As Shape
          Dim iSectIndex As Single
          Dim sSectionCollector As String
          Dim NewAgenda As Slide
          Dim AgendaLayout As CustomLayout

          'TODO reinstall ErrorHandler
10        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

20        If ActivePresentation.SectionProperties.Count < 2 Then
30            MsgBox "You seem to have not segmented/sectioned your presentation - therefore we can not create an automated agenda slide for you -- sorry." & vbCrLf _
                  & "Consider using the SEGMENT tools first.", vbOKOnly Or vbExclamation, "No Segments"

40            GoTo Ende
50        End If
          'Collect Section Titles


          'Search for Agenda Slide
60        Set oPl = ActivePresentation
70        For Each oSl In oPl.Slides

80            If oSl.CustomLayout.Name = "AGENDA" Then

AgendaContent:
90                sAgendaCnt = sAgendaCnt + 1
100               sAgendaIndex = oSl.SlideIndex
110               oSl.Select
120               Call ExcelWork_2020.Delay(0.5)

                  'Do the magic
                  'First Reset
130               DoEvents
140               Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("SlideReset")
150               DoEvents

                  'find the Textblock
160               oSl.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Agenda"
170               Set sAgendaTextblock = oSl.Shapes(1)
180               With sAgendaTextblock.TextFrame2
190                   If .HasText Then
200                   Debug.Print sAgendaTextblock.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text

210                       Select Case MsgBox("Your agenda slide has already text. Are you sure you want to overwrite this with the new headlines from the Segmentation?", vbOKCancel Or vbExclamation, "Agenda has text")
                             Case vbCancel
220                          GoTo Ende
230                          Case vbOK
                              'Continue
240                           End Select
250                   End If 'Even if there is no text, we will write now.
                                  'Call SectionWriter
260                               With ActivePresentation.SectionProperties
270                                   For iSectIndex = 1 To .Count
280                                       sSectionCollector = sSectionCollector & vbCrLf & ActivePresentation.SectionProperties.Name(iSectIndex)
290                                   Next iSectIndex
300                               End With
310                               sAgendaTextblock.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = sSectionCollector
320                               sAgendaTextblock.TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs(1, 2).Delete
330                               GoTo Ende
                      'End If
340               End With

350           End If
360       Next oSl

          ' No Agenda found - we create one
370           Set AgendaLayout = ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(6)
380           Set NewAgenda = ActivePresentation.Slides.AddSlide(2, AgendaLayout)
390           Set oSl = NewAgenda


400       GoTo AgendaContent:

410       GoTo Ende

ErrorHandler:
420       MsgBox "Something went wrong -- maybe you did not select the right object for this task? If you can't find the problem, send a mail to nik@xex.one with a short description of what you tried to achieve - we will get back to you as soon as possible", vbOKOnly Or vbExclamation, "Error"

Ende:
End Sub
```

Comment: Side note... why are you using `Single`? Should be `Long`.

Comment: Not familiar with the PowerPoint object model, but if `SectionProperties` is iteratable consider something like `For Each p In ActivePresentation.SectionProperties` instead for `For...Next`; object collections work better with `For Each` loops.

Comment: The PowerPoint for Mac VBA object model has lots of missing pieces compared to the Windows version. I would test your code, but you only posted a non-running snippet.

Comment: Hello @JohnKorchok thank you - yes - I am aware of "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/office-mac/idmsopowerpointmac" and "http://youpresent.co.uk/developing-vba-powerpoint-mac/" but I can't find more. Will paste the whole code (wanted to make it easy to spot the point)

Comment: Thank you @BigBen

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I am a bloody greenhorn in VBA - grateful for your input here!

Comment: @JohnKorchok here is the whole shebang - probably you guys will ROFL, but I am just a beginner. On another note I realized that my question was downvoted twice. Was this because I posted only snippets? Or because my question is so dumb? Would love to learn and get better here.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I tried your suggestion. (is that correct this way?)
   Dim iSectIndex As SectionProperties
    With ActivePresentation.SectionProperties
                                For Each iSectIndex In ActivePresentation.SectionProperties

                                Next iSectIndex

It throws 
438 - Object doesnt support this property or method
(in Windows Testing Environment)
The funny thing is: In my code version is works perfectly in Windows

Comment: Ok that settles it - error 438 is raised because VBA is looking for a hidden `_NewEnum() As IUnknown` member and can't find it, so the object collection can't be iterated with a `For Each` loop.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon thank you soo much for taking the time to look into this. I am very grateful. I am confused because the code runs under windows (and now miraculously also under Mac - but with the weird result I showed in the updated post with screenshots. This is really complicated for me

Comment: Not sure what's going on with the Mac, but given the output, seems you can easily make `sSectionCollector =  sSectionCollector & ActivePresentation.SectionProperties.Name(iSectIndex)`  conditional on `ActivePresentation.SectionProperties.Name(iSectIndex)` being a non-empty string?

Comment: Also get rid of these `GoTo` jumps, for your own sanity's sake. You want `Exit Sub` for most of these, and line 410 is unreachable (also.... [you don't want line numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41002482/1188513)).

Comment: @MathieuGuindon again thank you soo much. Line numbers I inserted only for here to make it easier to reference. Goto Jumps I know I am a bloody greenhorn. I did a little of DOS batch stuff when I was young and now this is all I can rely on :-(

I learned Exit Sub already but than the error handler would not kick in and I need to catch the errors so that the user has a clear info about what and why something is wrong. Is that a reason to keep going with the Goto's or is there still a better way=?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Line 410 is a standard code snippet which is part of my whole error handler at the end of a Sub. I agree in this case it will not be reached -- it's just there because its everywhere before my End Sub.

Comment: And everywhere it exists, it should be `Exit Sub` instead of `GoTo Ende` - keep the error-handling subroutine clearly separated from any non-error execution paths. If removing a `GoTo` jump changes how error handling works, then something is very broken and needs urgent fixing!

Comment: The only legit use of `GoTo` (and even then - it's arguable whether it's even legit), is to remove a nesting level inside a loop by jumping to a line label just before the `Next` token, when a loop's body must execute conditionally. In VB.NET you'd use the `Continue` keyword to skip an iteration, but VBA doens't have that so you can do `If Not {condition} Then GoTo Skip` (assuming the label is named `Skip`) - but as I said even that is disputable, because you could just as well do `If {condition} Then {loop body}` and have the entire loop body nested 1 level, and no need to jump anywhere.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Its funny because it is NEVER empty (as the output of Windows version does it correctly -- but I tried your suggestion, and it didn't change a thing. 
Like this? If ActivePresentation.SectionProperties.Name(iSectIndex) <> "" Then

Comment: So with vbNewLine I was not able to delete the parapgraphs. I used vbLf and then deleted lines instead of paragraphs -- that did it.
Thank you again @MathieuGuindon for your help. I can't upvote your answer, so I marked it as solution. Best vibes and keep safe!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here: `& vbCrLf &`

That's a line break on Windows (`Chr$(10)` & `Chr$(13)`), but Mac uses Linux-style line endings, and if your VBA code needs to run on both platforms, then the simplest way is to replace `vbCrLf` with `vbNewLine`.

`vbNewLine` will be `vbCrLf` on Windows, and `vbCr` on a Mac:

[learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/miscellaneous-constants)

> Platform-specific new line character; whichever is appropriate for current platform

That's what's causing the double-lines on Mac. Changing the hard-coded Windows-specific `vbCrLf` for `vbNewLine` will fix the line endings, fixing the problem.

Comment: YES! I found that out in my debugging right now --   was just working on that - and there is more to it -- Apparently in MAC the Paragraph.count is only 1 -- and it is udnerstood as LINES -- this is why I can't delete the first line!

Comment: Grr, My upwoting of your answer is not accepted, because I have no reputation.

Comment: Now I get this: 
"You've asked 4 questions recently, some of which have not been received very well by the community. Everyone learns at their own pace, and it’s okay to make some mistakes. However, the reception your questions have received thus far might ultimately block your account from asking questions entirely."

Hahaha - I guess I should stay out of the playground of the pros

Comment: @G.N.MS ...welcome to Stack Overflow, I guess! ;-) I *did* upvote this one, but consider editing the question (and tittle) to clean it up / remove the irrelevant fluff; this question will not just help *you*, it will live on to help others facing a similar issue. Help them find it by treating *them* as your audience! Every edit bumps the post back onto the front page, so make it worthwhile: the added attention might get someone to read your post and the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61594126/revisions) (see, no need to track changes in the post itself), and upvote the efforts!

Comment: "Every edit bumps the post back onto the front page, so make it worthwhile:"  OMG - I am so sorry. And thanks for the many tipps!

Comment: I think you meant (`Chr$(13)` & `Chr$(10)`). Also, I'm not sure if using `vbNewLine` is a good idea because Mac doesn't use `vbCr` since the introduction of Mac OS X (2001) apparently ([more info](https://superuser.com/questions/439440/did-mac-os-lion-switch-to-using-line-feeds-lf-n-for-line-breaks-instead-of)). New Macs use the Unix-style line endings (`vbLf`), so the edit at the top of OP's question is probably the correct answer.