# Excel VBA - Determine if a Module is included in a project

Tags: excel, vba, vbe

I am currently working on a project where I am unable to verify that all modules are installed. There is a growing group of modules being used for common functions for programs I work with. I have tried some solutions on the web which I couldn't use as I am unfamiliar with `Activeworkbook.VBProject.VBComponents()` methods.

It was mentioned that I should check tools reference for
Microsoft Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility and I checked that with no result. Any help would be appreciated. :)

References:

https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/284317-vba-function-check-if-particular-macro-exists.html

https://www.devhut.net/2010/12/09/ms-access-vba-determine-if-a-module-exists/

here is my code:

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Function Is_Module_Loaded(name As String) As Boolean
    Dim Module As Object
    Dim Module_Name As String
    Module_Name = name
    Is_Module_Loaded = False


    On Error GoTo errload
        Set Module = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(Module_Name).CodeModule

    Is_Module_Loaded = True

    If (0 <> 0) Then
errload:
        MsgBox ("MODULE: " & Module_Name & " is not installed please add")
        Stop
    End If

End Function
```

When Running the Code I don't get any error that is very helpful excluding my own which is reporting wrong saying my module is absent when it isn't.

Comment: This has a good overview of what's involved in tasks like this: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx   Have you set the "Trust access to VBProject" checkbox in Excel Options?

Comment: Note that all you can do is verify whether the VBA project contains a module that's named after what you're looking for - and that doesn't necessarily mean that's the actual module you want with the contents you need it to have. Consider having a copy of the module you want in `ThisWorkbook`, and using the VBIDE API to replace the module with it if it exists in the target project, or add it if it doesn't. Now, instead of a hand-crafted error message that's actually suppressing the would-be helpful error, consider `MsgBox Err.Description`. What's the *actual* error?

Comment: Mathieu Can you Elaborate on the ```MsgBox Err.Description``` part I am unfamiliar with this. I believe in the original I have no error even without my custom error message. also I was unable to figure out the VBIDE API but the idea of the code loading the modules from a location would be very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I believe I have found a solution.

**Credit to**: Tim Williams, Mathieu Guindon and Joe Phi (See link) for guidance to the solution

**Reference**: (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46727898/10297459)

**Noted problems:** With the original Tim mentioned that not setting a workbook could have me referencing the proper workbook, this was the major problem as I had other workbooks open that it was trying to reference.

```
    Option Explicit

Public Function Is_Module_Loaded(name As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean 
'!!!need to reference: microsoft visual basic for applications extensibility 5.3
        Dim j As Long
        Dim vbcomp As VBComponent
        Dim modules As Collection
            Set modules = New Collection
        Is_Module_Loaded = False

    'check if value is set

        If wb Is Nothing Then
            Set wb = ThisWorkbook
        End If
        If (name = "") Then
            GoTo errorname
        End If

    'collect names of files
        For Each vbcomp In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents

            If ((vbcomp.Type = vbext_ct_StdModule) Or (vbcomp.Type = vbext_ct_ClassModule)) Then
                modules.Add vbcomp.name
            End If

        Next vbcomp

    'Compair the file your looking for to the collection
        For j = 1 To modules.Count
            If (name = modules.Item(j)) Then
                Is_Module_Loaded = True
            End If
        Next j
        j = 0

    'if Is_module_loaded not true
        If (Is_Module_Loaded = False) Then
            GoTo notfound
        End If

    'if error
        If (0 <> 0) Then
errorname:
            MsgBox ("Function BootStrap.Is_Module_Loaded Was not passed a Name of Module")
            Stop
        End If
        If (0 <> 0) Then
notfound:
            MsgBox ("MODULE: " & name & " is not installed please add")
            Stop
        End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: updated to add the workbook as a second parameter

Try this:

```
Sub tester()

    Debug.Print Is_Module_Loaded(ThisWorkbook, "Module4")
    Debug.Print Is_Module_Loaded(ActiveWorkbook, "Module4")

End sub


Public Function Is_Module_Loaded(wb as Workbook, name As String) As Boolean

    Dim Module As Object

    On Error Resume Next
    Set Module = wb.VBProject.VBComponents(name).CodeModule
    On Error GoTo 0

    Is_Module_Loaded = Not Module Is Nothing

    If Not Is_Module_Loaded Then
        MsgBox ("MODULE: " & name & " is not installed in '" & _
                wb.Name & "' please add")
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: so I tried out this and module is not being written to the object stays with nothing inside it. the module name that I am using it on is named DEV_BE and when run it says its still not there. still having trouble understanding what I might of goofed.

Comment: Comment out the "on error resume next"  - do you get an error?  If Yes what is it?

Comment: I then get a error stating "Run-time error '9': subscript out of range. my variables currently say name = "DEV_BE" as string, is_module_loaded = false as bool, module = nothing as object.     DEV_BE is a name of a module in my environment.

Comment: Sounds like the function is working as expected, so perhaps it's a problem with exactly how you're calling it?  Or maybe it's looking at the wrong Workbook?  It might be better to add the workbook as a second parameter, so you can specify the exact place to look, instead of defaulting the the active workbook.

Comment: Hmm I will play around with that I didn't think about specifying it to a workbook but I don't see why I cant. will report back soon