# Copy only written code (Text) in VBA components (Modules,ThisWorkBook)

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel Macro-Enabled Report workbook with some codes in each of it's sheets (including "ThisWorkBook" component) which generates a Macro-Free version of it for my boss review. My boss almost always made some modifications on that ".xlsx" file and I want to transfer all of my written codes to this edited Macro-Free book and save it as ".xlsm" again.

How can I access and copy only the written codes inside those components?

Comment: What do you mean by "only the written codes"? Are there code written on the fly? Assuming that you want copying existing code from each module, would it be a correct assumption? So, you send a .xlsx file, your boss modify it and you want copying all the existing code from Macro-Enabled Report workbook to it. Is this understanding correct? And is the received answer (from @FunThomas) not convenient for you? It should be an inteligent solution. At least, on my taste...

Comment: Sorry for my misleading expression. I wanted to emphasis on code itself (not the whole module/component). I looked at the link @FunThomas provided at the first line of his answer but I haven't find a direct method to copy the code from each component on that page.

Comment: Do you like better the slogan: 'Why simple when complicated is possible'? I can show you how to copy the code, but why doing that, since it is not (strictly) necessary? If you do not like the suggested solution (sending the Macro-Enabled Report workbook for review), why exporting/importing solution is not convenient, and copying of the code is?

Comment: @FaneDuru Reason is my boss doesn't like/trust and not comfortable with any macro-enabled file.

Comment: Put the code into an Add-In instead that only you use, and have it process the macro-free workbook you are sending back and forth.

Answer (score 1):

Copying VBA code is possible (see for example [Copy all VBA codes from workbook to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61867907/copy-all-vba-codes-from-workbook-to-another)), however it's not that easy.

I would suggest the following alternatives:

**1)** Send the file as XLSM-file for review. If you want to prevent that certain macros are executed, you can create a small function (make it a function instead of hardcode the username at every place so that you can easily change it).

```
Function UserMacrosAllowed() As Boolean
    UserMacrosAllowed = (Environ("UserName") = "milad")
End Function
```

Then, put the following statement at the top of a routine that shouldn't be executed by your boss, eg:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not UserMacrosAllowed Then Exit Sub
    (...)
End Sub
```

**2)** If that's not feasible, create a template file without any data, just with all the code, and copy the *data* of the xlsx-file into it. This should be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Using The link provided by FunThomas I came up with my solution which is:

```
Sub ExportCodes()

Dim newWithMacro as workbook

For Each Component In ThisWorkBook.VBProject.VBComponents
    If Component.Type = 100 And Component.CodeModule.CountOfLines <> 0 Then
        Text = Component.CodeModule.Lines(1,Component.CodeModule.CountOfLines)
        newWithMacro.VBProject.VBComponents(Component.Name).CodeModule.AddFromString (Text)
    End If
Next Component

End sub
```