# Is there a way to cycle through all the modules in an excel sheet, and delete them all?

Tags: excel, vba, module, cycle

This is my current code.
It works for what I need it for, I just wonder if there is a way to cycle through the modules rather than having to type out the name of each one.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
    TempFileName = "Cable Rework" & " " & Format(Now, "mm-dd-yy") 'this names the temp file as the Pallet request followed by the current date and time
    FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 51
     
wb.SaveCopyAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

Workbooks.Open (TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr)

With ActiveWorkbook

    .VBProject.VBComponents.Remove .VBProject.VBComponents("Module1")
    .VBProject.VBComponents.Remove .VBProject.VBComponents("Module2")
    .VBProject.VBComponents.Remove .VBProject.VBComponents("Module3")
    .VBProject.VBComponents.Remove .VBProject.VBComponents("Module4")
.Save
.Close
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36791473/vba-getting-the-modules-in-workbook

Comment: Side note: better to use a workbook variable: `Dim wb2 As Workbook`, `Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr)`, `With wb2`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a [For Each](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/for-eachnext-statement) Loop, you can loop through the whole collection of `VBComponents` and decide which ones need to be deleted. The collection also contains "Document Modules"
one for each `Worksheet` as well as `ThisWorkbook` so you may not want to delete everything.

You can check the type of each component with the `VBComponent.Type` property. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/visual-basic-add-in-model/properties-visual-basic-add-in-model#type) is the list describing the different types (go to the second table). Standard Modules are 1, Class Modules are 2, User Forms are 3.

Once you have the For Loop, and you just need to check if `Type` is equal to 1, 2 or 3 and then call `VBComponents.Remove`.

```vb
Sub Example()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        
        TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
        TempFileName = "Cable Rework" & " " & Format(Now, "mm-dd-yy") 'this names the temp file as the Pallet request followed by the current date and time
        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 51
         
    wb.SaveCopyAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr)
    
    Dim VBComp As Variant
    For Each VBComp In wb.VBProject.VBComponents
        If VBComp.Type = 1 Or VBComp.Type = 2 Or VBComp.Type = 3 Then
            wb.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove VBComp
        End If
    Next
    wb.Save
    wb.Close
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Note: Normally, looping though a collection while removing items from that collection has a high chance of causing problems with the looping element. But I didn't encounter any issues with this loop, so I didn't do the usual work-around of saving the to-be-deleted objects into an array and then deleting them afterwards.