# insert macros in excel using R or cmd

Tags: r, vba, excel

I have the following problem: R script creates `.xlsx` file with a table where one of the columns is comprised of images (one image per cell) using `openxlsx` library. I need to align images in the center of the corresponding cells which seem to be impossible to do by means of `openxlsx` package. Therefore, I have written a simple `VB script(macro)` which may do it and want to embed this macro in excel using R or cmd(since R may call system comands). 
Could it be possible?

Here is the macro if it is needed:

```
Sub mymacro()
 Dim Ran As Range
 Dim Sh As Shape
 For Each Sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
  Set Ran = Sh.TopLeftCell
  Sh.Left = Ran.Left + (Ran.Width - Sh.Width) / 2
  Sh.Top = Ran.Top + (Ran.Height - Sh.Height) / 2
 Next Sh
End Sub
```

Comment: You can take a look at [How to add excel 2010 macro programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493473/how-to-add-excel-2010-macro-programmatically) - it *might* be possible to port it to VBScript. If the `openxlsx` supports it, creating the file from a macro-enabled template containing the code would be the simplest solution.